# How to pass varbinary(max) value as a parameter from view to actionmethod in the controller and save it to another table

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to take and pass a varbinary(max) image value from the view to an action method in my controller.and trying to insert the same value to another table field. please anyone help me

This is my view

```
@Html.ActionLink("- Add To Wishlist", "AddToWishlist", "Products", new { id = item.ProductID,img=item.ProductImage , id2=item.ProductCategoryID}, new { onclick = "wish(id);", @class = "fa fa-heart-o" })
```

this is  my controller

```
public ActionResult AddToWishlist(int id,byte[] img,int id2)
{

    TBL_WishList wish = new TBL_WishList();
    wish.WProductID = id; 
    wish.Wimage = img;
    wish.WCategoryID = id2;
    wish.WUserID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"].ToString());
    DateTime s = DateTime.Now;
    wish.WInsertDate = s;
    db.TBL_WishList.Add(wish);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("productlistmain1");
}
```

**ERROR:**

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

table design:https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXQPJ.png

Comment: I think using byte array in action argument becomes source of your problem. Try using `HttpPostedFileBase img` instead of byte array (please show your model class & file upload view code to assist me getting proper solution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just pass the base64 as parameter and increase the limit of url string capacity it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Use HttpPostedFileBase img for getting the image from view to controller

In controller you have to convert image to byte[]

Which would be something like this

```
byte[] arr = new byte[img.ContentLength];
img.InputStream.Read(arr, 0, img.ContentLength);
```

You can now pass the value to your DB.
This is how image to byte[] conversion works

For your exception i think you might have converted image to byte[] and passed it as string format so c# will assume it to be base64 string

There are various online converters to convert image to byte[]  and base 64 string,try them and make sure you get the same value.

Comment: i just pass the base64 as parameter and increase the limit of url string capacity it worked for me